# Getting exceptions after upgrade from Spring security 3 to Spring security 4?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-security

I used Spring security 3 with no problems. After upgrading to 4 problems.

So far I changed version numbers from `build.gradle`, all xml config files and deleted gradle's cache and downloaded everything again.

According to [this doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html) Changed security http element from this:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
        access-denied-page="/#/not-authorized">
```

To this:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/#/not-authorized"/>

</security:http>
```

Now if I run my spring web app I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#40a99380' of type [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter] 
while setting constructor argument with key [7]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#40a99380': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationEntryPoint' while setting bean property 'authenticationEntryPoint'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'authenticationEntryPoint' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/rest-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint]: 
No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
```

Why am I getting this exception and how to solve it?

----------- edit 1 ------------

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" order="0"/>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <import resource="rest-common.xml" />
    <import resource="rest-security.xml" />
    <import resource="rest-servlet.xml" />
    <import resource="rest-mongodb.xml" />

</beans>
```

rest-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
                                                                                        <!-- spring-security 3.2 -> 4.0  -->
    <security:http pattern="/rest/**" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="response403EntryPoint"/>

    <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/#/not-authorized"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="jsonAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationManager" class="com.myal.security.CustomAuthenticationManager" p:username="admin"
        p:password="admin" />

    <bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:defaultFailureUrl="/rest/security/login-failed" />

    <bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        p:defaultTargetUrl="/rest/security/check" />

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        p:loginFormUrl="/#/login" />

    <bean id="response403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>

    <bean id="jsonAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.myal.security.JsonAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager" p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <security:authentication-manager />
</beans>
```

rest-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
                                                                                        <!-- spring-security 3.2 -> 4.0  -->
    <!-- Has to be defined in same context where beans are scanned -->
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
        authentication-manager-ref="customAuthenticationManager" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"
        order="1" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" cache-period="300" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" cache-period="300" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/partials/**" location="/partials/" cache-period="300" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" cache-period="300" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" cache-period="300" />

    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"></bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <!-- init -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myal.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myal.rest" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x (XML Configuration)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html) chapter [4.7.5. LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-web-luaep)

> The LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint default constructor and the
>   setLoginFormUrl method was removed in favor of constructor injection.
>   For example:
>
> `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint();
>   entryPoint.setLoginFormUrl("/login");`
>
> should be replaced with
>
> `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = 
>   new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(loginFormUrl);`

According to this replace

```
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    p:loginFormUrl="/#/login" />
```

with

```
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/#/login" />
</bean>
```

*BTW: I strongly recommend that you read the complete [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x (XML Configuration)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html) guide*